# Get output from a while loop

Tags: bash

I have a file with dates where i want the dates to change to the day of the week using bash. I did this by the following while statement:

```
while read p; do
    date -d $p +%A
done <dates.txt
```

This works fine, but now i want the output of this statement in a file, say output.txt.

I tried

```
while read p; do
    date -d $p +%A
done <dates.txt >output.txt
```

But this gives the error date: extra operand '+%A'

Comment: I guess you want `while IFS= read -r p; do date -d "$p" +%A; done > output.txt`

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure no change was made to `dates.txt` in-between the code change? Please note double quotes around `$p` in KamilCuk's suggestion, that's generally important.

Answer (score 2):

It worked, thanks for the help.

I now have

```
while IFS= read -r p; do
   date -d "$p" +%A
done <dates.txt >output.txt
```